# how to attach an external terminal to devcontainer?

Tags: terminal, iterm2, vscode-devcontainer

I use iterm and would like to attach it to an active devcontainer workspace rather than use the integrated terminal.

I am able to exec into the container manually from iterm but that does not carry over all the settings and env vars that VSCode provides in the integrated terminal.

I discovered this when trying to use SSH credentials. From the integrated terminal the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is correctly used and I am able to use SSH for cloning repos. However, when I manually exec into the container from ITerm I am not able to connect to the SSH agent (indicating, as expected, that some settings and env vars have not carried over).

Is it possible to attach and if so, how?

> Here is an example of what I mean (integrated terminal on top, ITerm terminal undernath)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Confirmed [by one of the maintainers](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/110050#issuecomment-995855982)

> This correctly opens a local terminal now. There's no plan to allow it to connect to the remote, this would need to be a feature in the ssh/containers extensions.